# User.Identity.Name returning empty string

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication

User.Identity.Name returning empty string in Firefox. In IE it's working fine. I have an ajax call to controller and used the Identity to fetched data from DB. Problem is it will always return an empty string in Firefox. I already assigned cookie name in my webconfig under .

Comment: In the Ajax request, is the forms-auth cookie being sent? Use an http sniffer like firebug or fiddler to check.

Comment: yes! I don't any forms-auth cookie sent. I have no idea also of how to send forms-auth cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samer,

What authentication method are you using?

Forms Authentication
Windows Authentication
No Authentication

If you're using Forms Authentication, there are some steps you have to go through before User.Identity.Name is populated. Also, Firefox doesn't like sending the currently authenticated user (in Windows) to the web server. There is a setting you can change so it will, but depending on your deployment, that may not be feasible.

Dylan

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes i already have the Form Authentication work on my pages. The only problem I have is in Firefox that If I do ajax request using Jquery the User.Identity.Name is always empty.